# How to Add spinner dynamically to tablerow in android?

Tags: android, layout

i want to add spinner dynamically inside table like this image and how to specify its width and height also :

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @SamirMangroliya  sorry but i dont have any specific no. of colums i just want to add it as per my requirement..Any clue??

Answer (score 0):

Take a TableLayout form xml and inflate the xml to your code.
Now you can add new TableRows to the tableLayout using 
addView(new TableRow())...

And again u can addView(View v) to each table Row.
U can addWeight to each TableRow you add to TableLayout..In your case

TableRow weight will be 2

```
addView(new TextView())
addView(new Spinner())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add as many table rows as you want:

```
"TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutFromXML);"
"TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);"
"tableRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                          LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));"
"tableRow.addView(WhatEver view that you want);"
"tableLayout.addView(tableRow);"
```

view that you want add to tablerow, you can also set their attributes like "width" or "height".

Answer (score 0):

I know i am bit late, but you can try this.....

```
final TableLayout dynamicTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.hotelTableLayout);

                     /* Create a new row to be added. */
                    final TableRow row = new TableRow(Hotels.this);
                    row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    /* Create a component to be the row-content. */
                    SpnAdult = new Spinner(Hotels.this);
                    SpnAdult.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,
                            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
                    SpnAdult.setAdapter(adapter);

                    /* Add Spinner to row. */
                    row.addView(SpnAdult);

                    /* Add row to TableLayout. */
                    dynamicTable.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                            TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Hope this helps....